# de singulier ou de pluriel

Tags: accord, pluriel, de

Doit-on mettre la phrase au pluriel :

> Je n'ai jamais acheté de journal

Je reste plus convaincu du singulier même si le pluriel ne me semble pas faux.

> Je n'ai jamais monté de cheval aussi grand...

> Je n'ai jamais monté de chevaux aussi grands...

Quelle est la règle ?

Answer (score 2):

Si tu parles d'un seul cheval, ce cheval en particulier qui est très grand, le singulier, si tu parles d'un groupe de chevaux tous plus grands que ceux que tu as déjà montés, au pluriel.

> Je n'ai jamais monté de cheval aussi grand... que celui-là.

> Je n'ai jamais monté de chevaux aussi grands... que ceux-là.

Pour le journal, on s'attend plus au singulier :

> Je n'ai jamais acheté de journal = je n'ai jamais acheté aucun journal.

Le pluriel peut passer si on fait référence à l'activité  « acheter des journaux » :

> J'ai souvent acheté des magazines pour les clients de l'hôtel mais je ne leur ai jamais acheté de journaux.

Answer (score 1):

L'emploi du pluriel avec la négation manque de logique: Ce qui est nul c'est ce qui est "pas un" et non "pas pluriel": l'usage du singulier est donc meilleur, même si le pluriel est couramment utilisé, car la privation du pluriel, c'est le singulier ou le néant, tandis que la privation du singulier est le néant seul:

Voilà pourquoi, hormis les cas où l'objet désigné s'emploie toujours au pluriel ("les lunettes","les ciseaux", etc...), il est plus correct d'écrire :

> "Je n'ai pas de chien"

plutôt que

> "je n'ai pas de chiens"

.

Answer (score 1):

[**jamais lu de journal/journaux**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+lu+de+journal%2Cjamais+lu+de+journaux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20lu%20de%20journaux%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

On  trouve le pluriel mais pas le singulier.

[**jamais monté de cheval/cheveaux**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+mont%C3%A9+de+cheval%2Cjamais+mont%C3%A9+de+chevaux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20mont%C3%A9%20de%20cheval%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20mont%C3%A9%20de%20cheval%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

On trouve le singulier mais pas le pluriel.

[**jamais pris de bain,jamais pris de bains**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+pris+de+bain%2Cjamais+pris+de+bains&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20pris%20de%20bain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20pris%20de%20bains%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20pris%20de%20bain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20pris%20de%20bains%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Le singulier est beaucoup plus courant.

[**jamais vu de femme(s)**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+vu+de+femme%2Cjamais+vu+de+femmes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20vu%20de%20femme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20vu%20de%20femmes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20vu%20de%20femme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20vu%20de%20femmes%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Le singulier l'emporte mais le pluriel n'est pas si rare.

[**jamais connu de femme(s)**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+connu+de+femme%2Cjamais+connu+de+femmes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20connu%20de%20femme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20connu%20de%20femmes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20connu%20de%20femme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20connu%20de%20femmes%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Le singulier est plus courant.

[**jamais eu de voiture(s)**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+eu+de+voiture%2Cjamais+eu+de+voitures&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20eu%20de%20voiture%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20eu%20de%20voiture%3B%2Cc0)

Seulement le singulier se trouve.

[image]

[**jamais construit de maison(s)**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+construit+de+maison%2Cjamais+construit+de+maisons&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20construit%20de%20maison%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20construit%20de%20maisons%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20construit%20de%20maison%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20construit%20de%20maisons%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[**jamais acheté de maison(s)**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+achet%C3%A9+de+maison%2Cjamais+achet%C3%A9+de+maisons&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20achet%C3%A9%20de%20maison%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20achet%C3%A9%20de%20maison%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[**jamais vu de chameau(x)**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jamais+vu+de+chameau%2Cjamais+vu+de+chameaux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjamais%20vu%20de%20chameau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20vu%20de%20chameaux%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjamais%20vu%20de%20chameau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjamais%20vu%20de%20chameaux%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Les deux sont possibles, le singulier étant souvent plus fréquent, mais le singulier peut être la seule option en considération du nombre possible qui est à considérer suivant le contexte (acheté de maison, eu de voiture, etc.).